# Как увеличить сочность цвета (scss)?

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

Допустим имеется цвет `#ff7fa1`, как средствами `scss`:

1. Увеличить его сочность до максимального уровня `#ff0044`?
2. Уменьшить его сочность до минимального уровня `#ffffff`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно обратиться к цветовой [схеме`hsl`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/HSL)

При этом *максимальная сочность* цвета будет при значении `50%` для `l` компоненты и минимальная (белый цвет) - при значении 100%.

В SASS есть функция получения `l` компоненты: [`lightness($color)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lightness-instance_method)

А также функции для изменения этой компоненты:

- [`lighten($color, $amount)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method)
- [`darken($color, $amount)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method)

Таким образом для решения пункта два, нужно дополнить значение компоненты до `100`, а для решения первого пункта в случае если текущее значение больше 50 - уменьшить, в противном случае - увеличить до 50.

Пример использования:

```
.c1{
  color: lighten($color, 100-(lightness($color)));
}

.c2{
  $l : lightness($color);
  color: if($l > 50, darken($color, ($l)-50), lighten($color, 50-($l)));
}
```

При `$color: #ff7fa1` преобразуется в следующее:

```
.c1 {
  color: white;
}

.c2 {
  color: #ff0044;
}
```

используется [функция `if`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#if-instance_method)